# regex for comma separated values

Tags: java, regex

I am new to write regular expressions so please help.

I want to match this pattern (in Java):

```
"ABC",010,00,"123",0,"time","time",01,00, 10,    10,88,217," ",," "
```

the data I get will always be in the above format with 16 values. But the format will never change.

I am not looking for parsing as this can be parsed by java split too.
I will have large chunks of these data so want to capture the first 16 data points and match with this pattern to check if I received it correctly else ignore.

so far I have only tried this regex:

```
^(\".\"),.,(\".\"),.,(\".\"),(\".\"),.,.,.,.,.,.,(\".\"),.,(\".\")$
```

I am still in the process of building it.

I just need to match the pattern from a given pool. I take first 16data points and try to see if it matches this pattern else ignore.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please show some of your efforts. We will be glad to help you out.

Comment: I just tried this......this isn't correct but i am still building it.     ^(\".\"),.,(\".\"),.,(\".\"),(\".\"),.,.,.,.,.,.,(\".\"),.,(\".\")$

Comment: @Ikshvak Insted of comment, better you edit that in question. Also give your expected input. expected output so that it will be easy to understand.

Comment: `.` is just a single character, try replacing them with `.*?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick. Keep in mind that he doesn't care what order the data points occur in (ie. they could all be strings or all numbers).

```
(\s?("[\w\s]*"|\d*)\s?(,|$)){16}
```

You can try it out [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5Cs?%28%22%5B%5Cw%5Cs%5D%2a%22%7C%5Cd%2a%29%5Cs?%28,%7C%24%29%29%7B16%7D&input=%22ABC%22,010,00,%22123%22,0,%22time%22,%22time%22,01,00,%2010,10,88,217,%22%20%22,,%22%20%22).

Comment: +1, Tried it, worked for given input only after replacing your two `?` with `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Please find in the below code comprising comma separated evaluation for **String**, **Number** and **Decimal**.

```
 public static void commaSeparatedStrings() {       
    String value = "'It\\'s my world', 'Hello World', 'What\\'s up', 'It\\'s just what I expected.'";

    if (value.matches("'([^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\])*)[\\w\\s,\\.]+'(((,)|(,\\s))'([^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\])*)[\\w\\s,\\.]+')*")) {
        System.out.println("Valid...");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid...");
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
public static void commaSeparatedDecimals() {
    String value = "-111.00, 22111.00, -1.00";
    // "\\d+([,]|[,\\s]\\d+)*"
    if (value.matches(
            "^([-]?)\\d+\\.\\d{1,10}?(((,)|(,\\s))([-]?)\\d+\\.\\d{1,10}?)*")) {
        System.out.println("Valid...");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid...");
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
public static void commaSeparatedNumbers() {
    String value = "-11, 22, -31";      
    if (value.matches("^([-]?)\\d+(((,)|(,\\s))([-]?)\\d+)*")) {
        System.out.println("Valid...");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid...");
    }
}
```